# Dynamic Persistent Menu problem / module alternatives

Tags: 7, routes

I'm using Dynamic Persistent Menu (DPM) but I can't make it work. I have a Main Menu, most of the items have children, and since I don't want those parents to be links I'm using Special Menu Items module (I mention this in case there could be a conflict).

I installed DPM; then go to config > User interface > DPM, add new and select Main Menu as the Menu Root and save. I haven't found any steps to follow from there, so I figured that was it, but the children items do not show up. I tried enabling the DPM block but then I get a blank site.

Anyone who has used this module, could you guide me through it? I need the exact functionality this module provides, and from what I've seen neither Superfish nor Nice Menus modules can do this.

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you mention, their is a conflict between the Dynamic Persistent Menu and Special Menu Items modules.

Dynamic Persistent Menu adds a CSS class (`.dynamic-persistent-menu-menu-item`) to all `<li`> elements of a menu that is overridden by Special Menu Items.

This bug comes from the special_menu_items.module file, line 64. You can remove the following code:

```
$element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'nolink';
$element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'separator';
```

EDIT: The main bugs come from Dynamic Persistent Menu. As you know, the `class` attribute passed to `theme_menu_link()` should be an array, but in Dynamic Persistent Menu a string is passed.

So your WSOD (blank page) comes from `theme_dynamic_persistent_menu_menu_item()` in Dynamic Persistent Menu, where a string is passed instead of array.

When Special Menu Items tries to override it, a fatal error is presented.

Comment: @ Mohammad.  It worked, thank you!  I would've not thought of looking into those specific lines so you saved me a lot of time and headaches :)